# Enable IIS before removing files

Tags: xml, wix, windows-installer

I am trying to install IIS on a machine, through an MSI, but also, I'm expected to delete the default files that will be in inetpub\wwwroot (a .HTM and .PNG). I have a batch file, which runs a single command to turn on the IIS features I require:

`Start /w pkgmgr /iu:IIS-WebServerRole;IIS-WebServer;IIS-CommonHttpFeatures;IIS-StaticContent;IIS-DefaultDocument;IIS-DirectoryBrowsing;IIS-HttpErrors;IIS-ApplicationDevelopment;IIS-ISAPIExtensions;IIS-ISAPIFilter;IIS-NetFxExtensibility45;IIS-ASPNET45;IIS-NetFxExtensibility;IIS-ASPNET;IIS-HealthAndDiagnostics;IIS-HttpLogging;IIS-RequestMonitor;IIS-Security;IIS-RequestFiltering;IIS-HttpCompressionStatic;IIS-WebServerManagementTools;IIS-ManagementConsole;WAS-WindowsActivationService;WAS-ProcessModel;WAS-NetFxEnvironment;WAS-ConfigurationAPI`

I am currently installing the files (including the batch file), running the batch file to install IIS, but then I am unable to remove the default files, because the order of execution puts RemoveFiles before InstallFiles (understandably), so I've missed my opportunity to remove the files by waiting for the installation steps to finish. I'd much rather not change the order of execution to put InstallFiles before RemoveFiles (assuming that it's even possible).

Is it possible to remove these files after the installation? Or to run the batch file before the installation? I've considered creating another MSI to remove the files and adding it to the bootstrapper, but this seems excessive.

Comment: Why not just set your web site up somewhere else and leave IIS alone?  That's how I always do it.

Comment: These aren't my requirements. I don't have any say in how the site is set up.